# Random walk return for subgraph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

Assume that $G$ is a finite graph and we have a simple random walk starting at some vertex $v$ of $G$. We fix $n$, and consider the probability that the random walk does not return to $v$ after $n$ steps.

> Does this probability increase if we add finitely many edges and vertices to the graph? What if we add cycles?

This might have to do with Rayleigh's monotonicity but I'm not sure how prove it. If we add edges, then the effective resistance between any two vertices of $G$ will decrease. But we are also adding other vertices so the random walk can escape more easily.

Comment: If your $G$ is finite then I guess the answer is yes because you can start with a path of length n and then add edges to make it a $n \times n$ box.

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I misinterpreted your question. Sorry.

Comment: Adding one edge can make this probability decrease. Which small sized examples did you check?

Comment: So it depends on where we add the edges? I only checked it for $\mathbb Z$ and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

The probability does not necessarily increase.

Fix $n=2$, the set of vertices $V=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, the initial vertex $v=1$, and the initial set of undirected edges $E_0=\{(1,2), (2,3)\}$. The probability of returning to $v$ in $n$ steps is $1/2$. If we add the edge $(2,4)$ the probability of returning to $v$ in $n$ steps becomes $1/3$. Whereas if we add the edge $(1,4)$ the probability of returning to $v$ in $n$ steps becomes $3/4$.